# Clojure / Emacs jack in : Requiring a namespace on load

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen

When I start a lein repl for a Clojure project, the namespace clojure.repl is imported.

If alternatively I use Slime in Emacs with clojure-jack-in, I get a repl without this. (Leiningen 2)

How can I configure Leiningen (or Slime? or Clojure mode?) to import this at every start.

Comment: Hm. Maybe its just a bug in Leiningen 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Phil Hagelberg pointed out in
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/swank-clojure/UImhfeHikyM/tl0nd6-7YZMJ
the clojure.repl namespace isn't needed here: "Everything in that namespace has an 
equivalent in slime that works better".

The SLIME chapter of Nic Levines (draft of a) Lisp book is a excellent start to find out what SLIME does. http://lisp-book.org/contents/index.html
For the more experimentally inclined: The key bindings table starts at page 17 of that chapter.

Answer (score 2):

use inferior-lisp? some code from my .emacs:

```
;;; M-x inferior-lisp
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq safe-local-variable-values
                  '((inferior-lisp-program . "lein repl")
                    (inferior-lisp-program . "smvn clojure:repl")))))
```